# Сложность с дочерным элементом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки сворачивался текст, именно тот, который находиться в том же `<li>`, что и сама кнопка. Моя попытка закомментирована в коде.

```js
$(function() {

      $(".delete").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents(".wrap").remove();
      })

      /*
      
      $(".delete").on("click", function() {
        $(".text").slideToggle()
        
      */
})
```

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="delete">Удалить</button>
        <button class="roll_up">Свернуть</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        text1 text1 text1 text1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="delete">Удалить</button>
        <button class="roll_up">Свернуть</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        text2 text2 text2 text2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="delete">Удалить</button>
        <button class="roll_up">Свернуть</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        text3 text3 text3 text3
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest(".wrap")` -  будет искать ближайший подходящий элемент из числа следующих: сам выбранный элемент, его родитель, его прародитель, и так далее, до начало дерева DOM

`.find(".text")` - Осуществляет поиск элементов внутри уже выбранных элементов

```js
$(function() {
      $(".delete").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents(".wrap").remove();
      })
            
      $(".roll_up").on("click", function() {
        $(this).closest(".wrap").find(".text").slideToggle();        
      });      
})
```

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="delete">Удалить</button>
        <button class="roll_up">Свернуть</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        text1 text1 text1 text1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="delete">Удалить</button>
        <button class="roll_up">Свернуть</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        text2 text2 text2 text2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="delete">Удалить</button>
        <button class="roll_up">Свернуть</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        text3 text3 text3 text3
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```